# How can I install and configure ffmpeg on linux server?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ffmpeg

I need to generate thumbnail from an uploaded video in codeigniter. After some R&D I came to know that i need to install ffmpeg on my server so can anybody guide me for that?
My server is linux server.

Comment: You need to specify your linux distribution if you don't want to compile ffmpeg by yourself

Answer (score 1):

You can install ffmpeg from your linux distribution packet manager

Debian based distribution example:

> sudo apt-get install ffmpeg

Red-Hat based distribution example:

> sudo yum install ffmpeg

or you can download and compile ffmpeg manually

> wget http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-2.6.1.tar.bz2
>
> tar -jxf ffmpeg-2.6.1.tar.bz2
>
> cd ffmpeg-2.6.1
>
> ./configure
>
> make
>
> make install

If there will be problem with dependencies, install missing dependencies and try compiling again